# ASP.Net MVC routing issue with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, routes

This is my Action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(int SelectedID, int mode)
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.SelectedID = SelectedID;
    viewModel.Mode = mode;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
localservername/DManager/DManager/Index?SelectedID=9306270318&Mode=DataManager
```

And I am getting the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'SelectedID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, Int32)' in
>   'MscanES.Web.Areas.DManager.Controllers.DManagerController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter.
>       Parameter name: parameters

Clueless..

Comment: that error message seems to be talking about the `SelectedID`, which looks ok. But your `Mode` seems completely wrong. Are you sure thats the error your getting? `Mode` is an `int`, `DataManager` is not an `int`

Comment: If mode is enum, declare it as enum type, not as int

Comment: @Liam, archil, sorry I corrected it before hand but forgot to reflect in the url that I submitted here. But the real issue was with the Int range and it is solved with WeTTTT's help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# int (Int32) range is `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`. Your number `9,306,270,318` is obviously over the range, use Int64 instead.